Strange behavior of google-revocation-link-placeholder link/message
I'm trying to understand what is causing the Google Adsense Conesnt message to go 100% wide, across the whole screen, instead of placing the cute little tab to the bottom left of the screen on my website.
I have two websites and it's working fine on one of them. I would really appreciate if anyone have any clue on what is causing the message to go across the whole screen on one of them, which annoys me a lot.
Adsense code is inside TagManager on both sites.
It works perfectly here: www.kryssordkongen.no
Expanded:
Contracted:
It does not work as desired here: www.ordspill.com - 100% width

I inserted tags and code exactly on the site where it works. And have tried to tweak and adjust. I don't manage to change its behavior.
Update 11.06.2024
This is the TAG created in TagManager:
I also made two test files (link below). where I used Ordspill.com code on both ordspill.com and kryssordkongen.no. It still only works on Kryssordkongen, which leaves me even more confused.
https://www.ordspill.com/adsense-test.html
https://www.kryssordkongen.no/adsense-test.html
Update 12.06.2024
I made it even easier. I took the adsense code out of the TagManager and added the global adsense code directly in the header. As you can see it is the same code.
https://www.ordspill.com/adsense-global.html
https://www.kryssordkongen.no/adsense-global.html
How come it behaves differently?

Even if the tags are identical between the kryssordkongen and ordpsill websites, could you please edit the question to include them?

Hi SmellyCat, I updated the post with the information.

Another website with the same problem it seems:
https://www.favicon-generator.org/
